# Check if pixel is inside a polygon

Tags: silverlight

I want to know certain method so that i can tell if a pixel is inside a 4-point polygon or quadrilateral figure (not necessarily to be rectangle) given the 4 co-ordinates of that polygon.

I tried several methods, but none of them worked really well.

Thanx and Regards
Uday Gupta

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use areas : You first decompose your polygon into two triangles ABC and CDA, and check whether the point is in either triangle.

For that, assuming the triangle ABC for example and your point to test is M, you can test whether the area of the triangle ABC is equal to the sum of the areas of ABM + BCM + CAM.
Computing the area of a triangle is done using half the norm of the cross product.

Another solution that directly uses cross products can be found here:
http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html